# Django 'User' object has no attribute 'profile'

Tags: django, django-views

Can someone help me? I've been going around and around with questions here on SO but can't get the answer.

I'm getting `'User' object has no attribute 'profile'`

Here's my user model

```
class Profile(models.Model):

    NARRATESTATUS = (
        ('PAS', 'Passed'),
        ('REV', 'For_Review'),
        ('ACC', 'Narration_Accepted'),
    )

    TRANSLATESTATUS = (
        ('PSD', 'Passed'),
        ('RVW', 'For_Review'),
        ('ACP', 'Translation_Accepted'),
    )

    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, max_length=50, related_name='userprofile')
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    narrate = models.TextField(max_length=9999, default='Enter Narration')
    review_narration = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=NARRATESTATUS, default='Reviewing Narration')
    translate = models.TextField(max_length=9999, default='Enter Translation')
    review_translation = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=TRANSLATESTATUS, default='Reviewing Translation')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
           output_size = (300, 300)
           img.thumbnail(output_size)
           img.save(self.image.path)
```

I dont know why it's throwing `'User' object has no attribute 'profile'`

Someone familiar with this?

Comment: This is not in this view: it is the `home_view` where the error is produced. You probably should decorate with a `@login_required`. Since a user that did not log in, has of course no `Profile`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You're right. That fixed the error. Now I'm getting `'User' object has no attribute 'profile'` when I logged in.

Comment: @Highcenburg Show a `User` model

Comment: @Highcenburg  please send your profile model and user model if you write

Comment: @vorujack kindly see my edited question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your model doesn't make any sense. You have a many to many relationship between Profile and User. As the name implies, that means each user can have multiple profiles, and each profile can be associated with multiple users.

Surely that isn't what you want: you need a single user to be associated with a single profile, and that profile to belong to that user only. So you should use a one to one field.

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
```

Note two other changes: max_length is for strings, not relationships; and more to the point, since you want to access the Profile via `user.profile` you have to set the related_name to `profile`.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Now this is the error `no such column: aml_profile.user_id` Should migrating fix it?

Comment: Yes, you will need to run makemigrations and migrate.

Comment: I did and it returned a `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'User'` Why did it return that error?

Comment: Now I got this `no such table: aml_profile` I tried going in sqlite3 but did not see it. Is this a bug?

Comment: If you don't have any data you would mind losing, I would suggest deleting your sql file and all your migrations, then re-running makemigrations and migrate.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your app is available in settings.py INSTALLED_APPS

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `user` to `User`:

```py
User = models.ManyToManyField(User, max_length=50, related_name='userprofile')
```